# How to check if metadata is empty

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azureportal

I made an addMetadata class to add metadata to BLOB's that are stored in an Azure container. But before I want to add new metadata, I want to check for existing metadata and only if there's no metadata yet I want to do stuff. I tried the following code:

```
 if (properties.Metadata == null)
                    {
                        // Do stuff... 
                    }
```

where properties is a BlobProperties variable that was made from BlobClient.GetPropertiesAsync(). However this does not seem to work, does anybody have any other suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @fooourierou ,If below answer helps, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in my system

Try with using `blob.Metadata.Count` **which returns the  integer value if the metadata data not set it returns the 0 Else returns the count value of metadata in the blob  .Then Check the count value if it is 0 add the new metadata  data**

```
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Connection String");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test // container name");
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("caseno.txt //blob name");
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            Console.WriteLine("Blob metadata:");

            // Enumerate the blob's metadata.
            Console.WriteLine(blob.Metadata);
            //Check the blobs metadata 
            if (blob.Metadata.Count == 0)
            {
                blob.Metadata.Add("docType", "textDocuments");

                // Add metadata to the blob by using key/value syntax.
                blob.Metadata["caseno"] = "caseno";
                blob.SetMetadata();
            }
            foreach (var metadataItem in blob.Metadata)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tKey: {0}", metadataItem.Key);
                Console.WriteLine("\tValue: {0}", metadataItem.Value);
            }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

[image]